# Error in formatting when using JURI::current() to save to cookie

Tags: php, joomla, setcookie

I'm using the following to save the current URI to a cookie:

```
$redirect_address = JURI::current();
```

Then setting the cookie like this:

```
setcookie('redirect_to', $redirect_address, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");
```

Which is saving the value of the 'redirect_to' cookie as "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com/......"

The problem I'm having is that the page isn't redirecting when using:

```
$redirect = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">location.href = '";
$redirect .= $_COOKIE['redirect_to'];
$redirect .= "';</script>";
```

I think it's the funny characters it's replacing when saving the value in the cookie that's causing an issue? All of the resources I've found have said that this is the correct way to pass this to a cookie and perform the redirect, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the setcookie() line to use:

```
setrawcookie('redirect_to', $redirect_address, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", ".domain.com");
```

And that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php:

> Note that the value portion of the cookie will automatically be urlencoded when you send the cookie, and when it is received, it is automatically decoded and assigned to a variable by the same name as the cookie name. If you don't want this, you can use setrawcookie() instead if you are using PHP 5.

So it is correct that the value is HTML encoded. But it should also be automatically decoded; i just tested your example code and it redirects fine. I guess the typo was elsewhere.

Of course you can just go on using `setrawcookie`